# Algorithmic Complexity of Enqueue and Dequeue of a Special Queue

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, data-structures, queues

**The Canteen Queue Problem**

There is a common canteen for K hostels. Each hostel (co-ed) has some $N_1,N_2,...,N_K$ students. These students line up to pick up their trays in the common canteen, in a queue.
The queue is implemented as follows: If a student sees a person from his/her hostel, she/he joins the queue behind this person. This is the “enqueue” operation. The “dequeue” operation is as usual, at the front. How would we implement such a queue? Additionally, what would be the time complexity of the enqueue and dequeue operations? Would the average waiting time in this queue would be higher or lower than a normal queue?

Comment: you can search for Israeli queue, I'm thinking that the enqueue can be done in constant time by using a hash table and the average   waiting time is $O(n)$

Comment: Cross-posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4373402/14578, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/148942/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Comment: Please ask only one question per post.

Comment: @DaniTo Yes! Israeli queues seem to fit the bill. Thank you!

Comment: @KunindSahu Did any answer help you? So please accept the answer otherwise post your own answer and accept the answer. Because otherwise it's popping forever and looking for an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use a doubly linked list of students in the queue.  Also, for each hostel, have a second doubly linked list of students in the hostel, in the order they appear in the queue.  When a new student arrives, look up their hostel's linked list to find the person at the front of the queue, then add them to the queue.  All operations can be done in $O(1)$ time.